# How to get 50 points so I can comment on something that I think is useful information

Tags: power-supply, led, usb, usb-device, 5v

1.The problem is I need 50 points to be able to leave a comment on something and I feel the information is relevant.

2.I have went as far as making a name then attempting to comment only to find a very understandable prove you're not an idiot or troll or waste of time or insert whatever preference you have.

3.I have tried what I'm currently doing right now.

4.Bonus, yea I read all 3.  [Powering an LED from USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644123/powering-an-led-from-usb/644124#644124?newreg=7b7982d8da664a9b8b4247801d087366) This question is how I found myself here.